# Android - Help needed with designing a screen with either table layout or list views

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout, tablelayout

I am currently developing an Android app that is to be a counterpart to its sister iPhone prototype.

My task is to recreate the screen from a design mockup from the iPhone app in Android, as shown here:

[image: iPhone prototype]

What would be the best layouts / views to use for replicating this screen in an activity?

Thanks.

Comment: How many items do you think could be in this? Tens? Hundreds? Thousands?

Comment: As it will just be a proof of concept for now, it only needs to deal with a minimal amount of entries. Definitely not hundreds or thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not clear some things up. Also, I disagree with Ted Hopp's answer. I believe he is assuming that the medications will be filled statically, or something like that.

By the looks of your app, I assume you will be filling stuff dynamically, probably with many medications at once, or no medication at all. By the arrows in the iPhone mock-up, I also assume you will want to perform actions depending on the medication selected.

All that said, I would use a `ListView`. My general concept (the one I'd probably use) would be like this:

You have your data source, and use a Loader/LoaderManager/etc. to fill that into a `Cursor`. I'd feed this cursor to a `CursorAdapter` (perhaps a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, which seems likely and easy by looking at that UI concept --- won't need to customize the adapter part itself). Finally, this adapter would be used in the `ListView`. This is fairly easy and won't take much code (the ListView-SimpleCursorAdapter-Cursor stuff, the data logic is certainly custom).

You can then manage each of your clicks using the proper `ListView` listeners, IIRC. And act accordingly depending on the item selected. I'm guessing that the user would, for example, `startActivity` to see a detail about each medication.

However, as I said, if you have a fixed number of medications (here says an experienced former leukemia patient here, so I always assume medications vary widely!), a single `TableLayout` would do, but I feel that's not the case.

Ah, and about the layout for each component/med, as I said, a simple layout would do. Probably a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation. Again, very simple to implement with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback David. You are correct that eventually the list will be filled dynamically from an external data source. And tapping on each item would start a new activity with details about each Rx. I had been messing around with the table layout initially, but a list view (or the multi column list view as suggested by Ted) seem the easier route to go.

Comment: For a mockup, *do what he said*. However, if you ever implement the real thing, I *strongly* suggest that you implement a Loader, and it could be a Cursor loader (probably since it deals with typical data) or anything else. And, truth be told, what he used involves customizing a BaseAdapter, and that involves some lower level coding (item position, getItem, item ids, item counts, lots of stuff). If you'd use a CursorAdapter, you only really need to implement createView (one line of code) and bindView (where you actually do stuff with the custom layout).

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice example of how to do this with a custom row view [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/). This is probably the cleanest way to go.

The closest built-in widget for this is a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html). Take a look at the [Hello Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html) tutorial project for an example of this in action. You might want to wrap it in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: Thanks for the article Ted! I will give it a look over and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is highly dependent on the requirements. As I see it, you have (at least) a few options:

- TableLayout
- ListView
- Something custom

As David noted, the TableLayout is most appropriate if you have a fixed set of data, but you can make it work dynamically too simply by adding child views. The benefit of using the TableLayout is mainly a built-in implementation of columns, including dynamic column sizing based on contents. The down-side is the lack of built-in dynamic support, especially when working with large data sets.

A ListView is a better fit for dynamic and large data sets, but comes with the limitation of not supporting columns. Ted's link lets you simulate columns, but unlike TableLayout these columns have a fixed width (in percentage of the parent's width). The columns are not sized based on content. You could potentially try to do something to measure all the children, but it'd be tricky. It can also be mildly annoying to try to deal with headers in a ListView, though with a little searching you'll find plenty of resources to help you with this.

The third option is to roll your own [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) or [AbsListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html). Of course this involves a significant amount more work, but you could take a look at how TableLayout works and resize the columns based on the content. This would also get you support for adapters and all the benefits that come along with that. This is probably quite a bit of work though, especially resizing the columns based on content.

Consider whether your columns must resize to fit their content or not.